# Web Service / Seguridad Apache Axis compatible con JDK 1.4 / Configuración realizada en el App Server OAS

Tags: java, webservice, apache-axis

Tengo la siguiente clase `WSIntegracion.java` : Cuando invoco el servicio desde mi aplicación (Local) hacia el servicio desplegado en un servidor de aplicaciones OAS (Testing) si se logra respuesta del servicio, sin embargo cuando mi aplicativo esta desplegado en el mismo servidor donde se encuentra alojado el servicio no obtengo respuesta. Al inicio se caía en esta línea de código: `Envelope responseEnv = msg.receiveEnvelope();` ya que antes al invocar el servicio desde mi aplicación (Local) no obtenía respuesta sin embargo al agregar esta línea de código `System.setProperty("oracle.soap.transport.noHTTPClient", "true");` en el constructor ya podía obtener respuesta del servicio, el problema ahora es que el aplicativo desplegado con esta línea de código no obtengo respuesta del servicio.

parametros.properties

```
INTEGRACION = http://psdym03:7777/nstd/services/WSIntegracion
USUARIO = USUARIO
CLAVE = CLAVE
```

WSIntegracion

```
public class WSIntegracion extends WrappedDocLiteralStub 
{
        
    private ResourceBundle parametrosProperties = ResourceBundle.getBundle("seguridad.properties.parametros");
    private String _endpoint = parametrosProperties.getString("INTEGRACION");   
    private String _user = parametrosProperties.getString("USUARIO");
    private String _clave = parametrosProperties.getString("CLAVE");
    
    

    public WSIntegracionMccia(){   
        
        System.setProperty("oracle.soap.transport.noHTTPClient", "true");
        
        m_httpConnection = new OracleSOAPHTTPConnection();
        
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(OracleSOAPHTTPConnection.AUTH_TYPE, "basic");
        props.put(OracleSOAPHTTPConnection.USERNAME, _user);
        props.put(OracleSOAPHTTPConnection.PASSWORD, _clave);
        
        m_httpConnection.setProperties(props);
      
    }

    public String getEndpoint()
    {
        return _endpoint;
    }

    public void setEndpoint(String endpoint)
    {
        _endpoint = endpoint;
    }

    private OracleSOAPHTTPConnection m_httpConnection = null;
    private SOAPMappingRegistry m_smr = null;


    public String[] consultarListaCbssp(String idCenso, String tipoDocumento, String numeroDocumento, String nombreBeneficiario, String apellidoPaterno, String apellidoMaterno) throws Exception{
                
            URL endpointURL = new URL(_endpoint);
    
            Envelope requestEnv = new Envelope();
            Body requestBody = new Body();
            Vector requestBodyEntries = new Vector();
            
            String wrappingName = "consultarListaCbssp";
            String targetNamespace = "http://servicios.mccia";
            Vector requestData = new Vector();
            requestData.add(new Object[] {"idCenso", idCenso});
            requestData.add(new Object[] {"tipoDocumento", tipoDocumento});
            requestData.add(new Object[] {"numeroDocumento", numeroDocumento});
            requestData.add(new Object[] {"nombreBeneficiario", nombreBeneficiario});
            requestData.add(new Object[] {"apellidoPaterno", apellidoPaterno});
            requestData.add(new Object[] {"apellidoMaterno", apellidoMaterno});
            
            requestBodyEntries.addElement(toElement(wrappingName, targetNamespace, requestData));
            requestBody.setBodyEntries(requestBodyEntries);
            requestEnv.setBody(requestBody);
            
            Message msg = new Message();
           
            msg.setSOAPTransport(m_httpConnection);
            msg.send(endpointURL, "", requestEnv);
           
            Envelope responseEnv = msg.receiveEnvelope();
            Body responseBody = responseEnv.getBody();
            Vector responseData = responseBody.getBodyEntries();

            return (String[])fromElement((Element)responseData.elementAt(0), java.lang.String[].class);
            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actualiza esta sección, lo mas probable es que te falta el parámetro  `props.put(OracleSOAPHTTPConnection.REALM, "tuRealm")` si no lo tienes deberías consultarlo con el administrador del otro servidor.

```
public WSIntegracionMccia(){   

    m_httpConnection = new OracleSOAPHTTPConnection();

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(OracleSOAPHTTPConnection.AUTH_TYPE, "basic");
    props.put(OracleSOAPHTTPConnection.USERNAME, _user);
    props.put(OracleSOAPHTTPConnection.PASSWORD, _clave);
    props.put(OracleSOAPHTTPConnection.REALM, "tuRealm");
    m_httpConnection.setProperties(props);

}
```

Comment: Gracias Julio, se referencio el REALM en el properties y funcionó correctamente.

Comment: Vale, si te ayudo dale +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

A mi me parece que la configuración del servidor OAS es distinta a donde pruebas en local. Me he dado cuenta de eso porque tienes que modificar banderas como esta: `oracle.soap.transport.noHTTPClient`

Prueba usar esto en ambos servidores y verás que hay diferencias:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      Properties p = System.getProperties();
      p.list(System.out);
   }
```

Pide a tu administrador de OAS que modifique las configuraciones para que quede igual pero si no quiere por X o Y motivo tendras que hacerlo tu con `System.setProperty`.

Estas diferencias se dan por distintas versiones de java o porque la configuración está resolviendo a clases que tienen el mismo nombre pero están en otro paquete que usa OAS y tu no lo usas. Tu necesitas que se resuelva a clases que tu usas.